# testing private before filter that relies on request body in rspec

Tags: ruby, http, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, metaprogramming

I have the following controller:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!

  private
    def authenticate_user_from_token!
      @json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
      --auth logic goes here extracting user credentials goes here--
      request.body.rewind
      if auth_valid
         authenticate
      else
         render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
end
```

Testing this method has proven to be surprisingly difficult. I have tried the following approaches:

1) Sending the private method directly:

```
 @controller.send(authenticate_user_from_token!)
```

The flaw here, is that I am unsure how to mock out request.body to contain valid/invalid credentials. I have tried the following:

```
 before do
    class Hash
       def body
          self['body']
       end
    end
    @request = {}
    @request['body'] =StringIO.new({auth_goes_here}.to_json)
 end
```

However, in the method, request still gets overriden with a brand new `ActionController::TestRequest.`

2) Posting directly:

```
before do
  post :authenticate_user_from_token!, my_preconstructed_credentials, format: :json
end
```

which results in:

```
 *** AbstractController::ActionNotFound Exception: The action 'authenticate_user_from_token!' could not be found for ApiController
```

3) Defining an exposed method at runtime:

```
  before do
    @controller.class_eval <<-RUBY_EVAL
      public
        def update
        end
    RUBY_EVAL
  end
```

followed by `post :update`, which still results in `*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method`foobar' for #`

My question is: how can I test a private before filter on a controller that depends on request.body? I realize I could mock out request and body in my third approach, but I would still require it to respond to read/rewind. How is this kind of method usually tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the following worked:

```
before do
   class ::TestApiController < ApiController
      def hello
         render nothing: true
      end
   end

   Rails.application.routes.draw do
      match 'hello', to: 'test_api#hello'
   end
   @controller = TestApiController.new
   @request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = my_awesome_json
   post :hello
 end
```